# Identify corresponding elements in a correlation matrix using R?

Tags: r, matrix

Like all correlation matrices, this correlation matrix has corresponding elements, in **R**:

```
m <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")]
cor(m)
#>             mpg        cyl       disp
#> mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514
#> cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329
#> disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000
```

I.e., the cell for *cyl, mpg* has the same value as the cell for *mpg, cyl*.

How can I identify these corresponding, or reciprocal, cells?

I am asking because I am trying to identify pairs in network data. Social network data is often stored in an adjacency matrix, a matrix where the cells represent the presence (or the magnitude) of a relation.

Is there some straightforward way to do this?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Let me try to be more clear. For a given matrix *m*, I'd like a new matrix with every cell for which *i, j* = *j, i* (in *m*) to be indicated with a unique integer or character string.

Comment: Are the matrices always square?

Comment: Yes, they are always square

Comment: @markus actually, it's not that the value of cell *i, j* equals the value of cell *j, i*, but simply that cells *i, j* and *j, i* are indicated with the same integer or character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Here is an option using `outer`

```
out <- outer(1:4, 1:4, paste, sep = "-")
out[upper.tri(out)] <- sub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "\\2-\\1", out[upper.tri(out)])
out
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
#[1,] "1-1" "2-1" "3-1" "4-1"
#[2,] "2-1" "2-2" "3-2" "4-2"
#[3,] "3-1" "3-2" "3-3" "4-3"
#[4,] "4-1" "4-2" "4-3" "4-4"
```

**2)** This however is a much faster approach.

```
fun <- function(dims, fill = NA) {
  mat <- matrix(fill, nrow = dims, ncol = dims)
  mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- seq_len(sum(upper.tri(mat)))
  pmax(mat, t(mat), na.rm = TRUE)
}
fun(4, fill = 0L)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    1    2    4
#[2,]    1    0    3    5
#[3,]    2    3    0    6
#[4,]    4    5    6    0
```

Comment: I think this does it.